# Mac Pro failing to boot

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, startup

Two times now, over the last 3 weeks my Mac Pro is failing to boot. Once on, it stays on the blue screen with the spinning icon and never gets to the login screen. To remedy this I boot from install dvd, re-install Leopard and only then will it boot completely. COuld this be my HD is getting ready to fail?

Answer (score 1):

It will be best for you to run a S.M.A.R.T scan on the drive to see if its failing. You can do this by downloading the free trial of [Smart utility](http://www.volitans-software.com/smart_utility.php).

If the hard drive turns out fine or passes the S.M.A.R.T Scan then just re-install the operating system after you've backed up your data obviously.

Comment: Thanks, ran the the test and it says FAILING, now what?

Comment: Now you go and buy a new hard drive amigo.